# Margin in React-Native not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was trying to make an app on React-Native

To start, I did mere basic where I wanted to make a bottom Navigation

This is what I did at start to test

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet,  
    View, 
    Text, 
    Image
}  from 'react-native';

class MainScreen extends Component {

    constructor () {
        super () 
        this.board = []
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <View style={MainScreenBox}>
                 <View style={GridBox}>
                    <Text> Testing..........</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
    MainScreenBox: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
    },
    GridBox: {
        marginTop: "90%",
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5
    }
})

const {
    GridBox, 
    MainScreenBox
} = styles
```

Here, I did something as simple as `marginTop: "90%",` expecting the text would come at bottom but it still remains half way on the screen.

[image]

**Question:** Any Idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Add a flex weight (**flex:1**) to your main container.

```
MainScreenBox: {
    flex:1,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean all styles and put this to MainScreenBox style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
    MainScreenBox: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent:'flex-end'
    }
})
```

and use `style={styles.MainScreenBox}` to apply in root View. You can refer to [flex doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox) to see how FlexBox works. Also notice that flexDirection is column by default in react native you do not have to set it and display:"flex" neither.